# Checking whether a GeoServer service is WMS or WMTS?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, map-service, wmts

I'm using GeoServer 2.10.1 connected to a PostGIS database. I have created a new workspace and activated the `WMTS` checkbox in the workspace definition. The service URL always contains `wms` either when I activate WMS or WMTS option. Then, I guess that this is not a good way to check whether the service is WMS or WMTS...

The service URL is as follow:

```
http://my.server.fr/geoserver/myworkspace/wms?
```

A layer complete URL is a follow (copied from *Layer Preview* page):

```
http://my.server.fr/geoserver/myworkspace/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=test&styles=&bbox=1466568.5,6127476.88999999,1528548.733,6176365.98899999&width=768&height=605&srs=EPSG:3947&format=application/openlayers
```

I can't see any other place than the worspace definition where to specify this option for a given service (neither within stores or layers definition).

I need to make sure that the service is WMTS and not WMS. I have checked layers display within QGIS but I'm not able to find this information out within QGIS GUI.

Is there a simple way to check this out?

Comment: WMTS service is accessed through GeoWebCache and URL like http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities. The meaning of parameter "SERVICE" is quite obvious.

Comment: OK so how to create a WMTS service, then? It does not seem so obvious...

Comment: The integrated GeoWebCache should be on and available by default, and how to add layers to tiled service is documented in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/layers.html